# full rebuild every time when building by CMake on Linux from Windows shared folder

Tags: gcc, build, cmake, virtual-machine, share

I'm using a script to build Windows and Linux versions (from Windows). Linux build is done by `ssh`ing to Linux VM and running CMake build. Sources are located on Windows folder shared with Ubuntu VM.

CMake does full rebuild everytime, even if there's no changes since the last build. I suppose the problem is that CMake (or GCC?) doesn't get or reads incorrectly Windows NTFS timestamps.

Is there any cure for this?

CMake 3.7.1, GCC 4.9, Windows 10, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, VirtualBox 5.1

Comment: gcc is a compiler, not a build system.

Comment: @Rob: thanks, corrected

Comment: `I suppose the problem is that CMake (or GCC?) doesn't get or reads incorrectly Windows NTFS timestamps.` - The filesystem used for shared folders on VirtualBox doesn't provide correct file modification's timestamps. Because of that `make` tends to rebuild everything on such filesystem. I know no way except changing filesystem. For example, you may maintain git repo on Windows, and pull it on Linux.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: do you mean NTFS or some fancy filesystem implemented by VirtualBox for Windows shares? What I can change here?

Comment: Within *guest* OS this shared folders filesystem is known as "vboxsf". It is implemented specifically for VirtualBox virtual machine, so NTFS (or any other *host* filesystem) is unrelated to the problem. (But NTFS could be *partially* related to the problem because of implementation details of "vboxsf").

Comment: Which CMake generators are you using? If you use Ninja, for example, it can report to you why it wants to rebuild things with its `-d explain` option, which can be combined with the `-n` option to just explain things without actually building (so you can invoke it repeatedly and non-destructively for investigative purposes). That may help confirm or refute whether timestamps are the cause or whether something like symbolic links or mount points are confusing the dependency logic.

Comment: @CraigScott: unfortunately it's default `make` (`nmake`?)

Comment: Try the -d and -n options to the make command. You'll probably also get better performance if you use a dedicated virtual disk rather than one shared with the host anyway (that was my experience with another VM software package in the past).